# How to create cache key using pageable and object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-data-jpa

I have the below function

```
public Iterable<PageLayout> getAll(final Pageable pageable, PageLayout entity, List<String> exactSearchingFields, boolean ignoreOrga) {
        return super.getAll(pageable, entity, exactSearchingFields, ignoreOrga);
    }
```

I am trying to apply `@Cacheable`

```
@Cacheable(value = "PageLayouts", key = "#pageable.toString().concact('-').concat(#entity.toString())")
```

but the above key is caching but if we send arguments within the URL, it shows all the data.